# Continuous Random Variables: Uniform

Tags: probability-distributions

Problem:
A person drives to work via a road with a single traffic signal. The light cycles, green for 45 seconds, red for 15 seconds – ignore yellow. Assume the person approaches the signal at a random time. Please find:
a. the probability of having to stop at the light;
b. the expected delay time due to the signal.

Attempt at Solution:
I was able to deduce that given the total 60 seconds, the probability of the light being green is 75% and the probability of the light being red is 25%. This, however, is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I imagine you concluded that the probability of having to stop is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Now to the expected delay. **If** the light is green, the expected delay is $0$. **If** the light is red, by symmetry the average delay is $7.5$ seconds. Thus the average delay, in seconds, is
$$(3/4)(0)+(1/4)(7.5).$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "by symmetry"?

Comment: I am assuming that the time of arrival is uniformly distributed in the $15$ second interval that red is on, indeed in the minute that the light cycles through.  That implies that the mean wait is $15/2$.  The uniform distribution in the interval $[0,15]$ has mean $7.5$, since the density function is symmetric about $x=7.5$.